# TFS 2013 & VSO Problems with Build & Continuous Integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm going to start with a little background regarding a recurrent problem we've been having with TFS.

A short while ago we upgraded our in-house server to utilise TFS 2013. Some of our projects were embedded with build definitions and continuous delivery prior to the upgrade and worked perfectly. However, after finalising the upgrade our build definitions failed due to what the system assumed were missing files (mainly for `AspNetCompileMerge.targets`), but after investigating the issue we couldn't find the root cause.

To cut a long story short, we tried a number of ways to fix the problem, the only one which worked was by commenting out the below code within the affected application `CSPROJ` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == 
  ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, problem number 2 cropped up a few days later when we merged some of the projects onto VSO without the build definitions. The cause of the issue was due to me commenting out the above lines of code. After un-commenting the above code in the `CSPROJ` file and checking in the project everything started working again... **Until today!**

This morning I reimplemented the Build Defintions into the affected projects and tried publishing to VSO which is when I started getting the same error mentioned in paragraph 2. As I had already come across this issue before the fix was to comment the code out again.

The above information now leads me to the following questions

- Did something change in TFS 2013 for Build Definitions to not work correctly when the above code is implemented?
- Why is it that the above code needs to be removed when utilising Build Definitions in TFS 2013?
- Is the above code important when Build Definitions are enabled or disabled?

Obviously it isn't a be all and end all if we can check in without the code, however I would like to understand why it breaks on check in.

I initially assumed this was a misconfiguration on our server, however this bug is also evident in the online version as well so this theory went out of the window. The affected applications were originally built in VS 2012 on the MVC 5 platform if this helps.

Comment: That code says what version you're using, which determines which folder structure on disk its going to look in to find the .exe's it needs to finish builds. The files are "missing" because they don't exist in the local machine, based on the version number used.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. We determined it was a build definition version based on the research we did and the wording of the parameters. However, we checked 3 different workstations and the file it is looking for exists, we modified the arguments accordingly based on some other StackOverflow answers and nothing worked (the code you see in the above was our final attempt), even after doing a fresh install of VS 2013 on a separate machine to compare directories.